Optimized way to calculate the total across pages in Postgres
I want to write a query in Postgres where I need to calculate the total of a numeric field.
Example- Table Students



Class
ID
Name




A
101
John


A
102
Mark


A
103
Smith


B
104
Tom


B
105
Freb


B
106
Dan



Table Marksheet



Student Id
Mark




101
85


102
75


103
95


104
55


105
88


106
90



And I need the output of the query like this -



Totals
Class
ID
Name
Mark




Total



488


Total
A


255


Total
B


233


Total
A
101
John
85


Total
A
102
Mark
75


Total
A
103
Smith
95


Total
B
104
Tom
55


Total
B
105
Freb
88


Total
B
106
Dan
90



NOTE: I will remove the repeated Totals and group the class data using the UI.
I have written a query to get these data like this -
function getStudentMarks(limit numeric, offset numeric)
with filter_data as (
    select
        'Total' as total,
        st.class as class,
        st.id as id,
        st.name as name,
        st.mark as mark
    from Students st
    Limit limit Offset offset
    ) 
    (select
        'Total' as total,
        st.class as class,
        st.id as id,
        st.name as name,
        st.mark as mark
    from filter_data
    )
    Union all
    (
        select
            'Total' as total,
            st.class as class,
            null as id,
            null as name,
            sum(st.mark) as mark
        from filter_data
        group by 
            st.class
    )
    Union all
    (
        select
            'Total' as total,
            st.class as class,
            null as id,
            null as name,
            sum(st.mark) as mark
        from filter_data
    )

But this affects the pagination total, that is when the limit is 5, in the first only the sum of 5 rows is calculated but my expectation is I want the sum of all data on the first page itself, which can be achieved by giving the Limit and Offset condition in the first final select query, but since the Student table is big data table I couldn't get an optimized query (NOTE: I will join must join multiple tables so I have limited the output of parent table).

Expected - 
In the first page



Totals
Class
ID
Name
Mark




Total



488


Total
A


255


Total
B


233


Total
A
101
John
85


Total
A
102
Mark
75


Total
A
103
Smith
95


Total
B
104
Tom
55


Total
B
105
Freb
88



On the second page -



Totals
Class
ID
Name
Mark




Total
B


233


Total
B
106
Dan
90




Output of my query



Totals
Class
ID
Name
Mark




Total



488


Total
A


255


Total
B


143


Total
A
101
John
85


Total
A
102
Mark
75


Total
A
103
Smith
95


Total
B
104
Tom
55


Total
B
105
Freb
88



On the second page -



Totals
Class
ID
Name
Mark




Total
B


90


Total
B
106
Dan
90



Could we able to get the cumulative sum of the field in another flow? could anyone help me

See ROLLUP for group totals.

As immediately pointed out by @ValNik that's exactly what grouping sets and rollup are for. There's even a similar thread right next door:
demo at db<>fiddle
select class,id,name,sum(mark)
from students join marksheet on students.id=marksheet.Student_Id
group by rollup(class,id,name)
order by grouping(class,id,name) desc;




class
id
name
sum







488


A


255


B


233


A
102

75


A
101

85


A
103

95


B
106

90


B
104

55


B
105

88


B
106
Dan
90


B
105
Freb
88


A
103
Smith
95


A
101
John
85


B
104
Tom
55


A
102
Mark
75



As to pagination: if you used the opposite order, showing low-level totals first, you might get initial pages quicker because those only depend on a small subset of rows. Since you're trying to show totals first, the query needs to read the whole table before giving you the first page anyways.
You could consider paginating this with a plain SQL cursor.
